# override Postgres array type shift operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to override the `<<` operator for a postgres array type attribute created by ActiveRecord?

Column definition:

```
t.time "hours", default: [], array: true
```

This seems to work:

```
def hours=(arr)
  super(arr.map {|h| # do some stuff with each element})
end
```

This doesn't:

```
def hours<<(val)
  super(# do some stuff before pushing)
end
```

Note that this is not an association created by `has_many` where I can add a block to overload methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is defined in the Array class, so you can't do that in your model.

One way you can achieve that is through a mixin

```
module WithShift
  def << arg
    # do something 
  end
end


def hours
  read_attribute("hours").extend(WithShift)
end
```

This is slower. But it shouldn't be a show stopper. Here is some basic benchmark.

```
require 'benchmark/ips'
module WithShift
  def << arg
  end
end
def with_extend; [1,2,3].extend(WithShift); end

def base; [1,2,3]; end

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("base") { base }
  x.report("with extend") { with_extend }
  x.compare!
end


Calculating -------------------------------------
                base      5.506M (± 9.1%) i/s -     27.415M in   5.022561s
         with extend    349.984k (± 7.6%) i/s -      1.769M in   5.081799s

Comparison:
                base:  5505897.2 i/s
         with extend:   349984.1 i/s - 15.73x slower
```

Comment: Is there a performance / memory cost of including the module every time the hours attribute is used?

Comment: Yes, It's about 15x slower. But negligible unless you call this method a LOT of times. Also notice that `include` didn't work.  What you actually want to do is to use `extend`. I've edited my answer and added a benchmark

Answer (score 1):

Building on @ismael's answer, in ruby `=` is part of the setter's method name.

This code

`def hours= arr
end`

creates a method named `hours=` whereas `<<` is an operator, and isn't allowed as part of a method name. It *is* possible to define custom operators, and @ismael includes an example of how to do that.